# Laravel SQL 'Like wildcard' query issue , Why is the space braking this search?

Tags: sql, laravel

```
 return Patient::whereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ' , last_name) like '%" .$request->searchTerm. "%' ")->take(50)->get();
```

**Question**: When I add space to the input search it doesn't work as expected.

Example patient is John Smith

- input 'John' returns the patient
- input 'John ' returns the patient
- input 'Smith' returns the patient
- input 'Smith ' returns the patient

**input 'John Smith' returns 'no results'** <- Any ides why this is happening.
I am assuming its a lack of understanding on my part of how wildcards work but I'm a my whit's end.

Note: After googling this issue many of the answers I found suggested searching separately, I do not want to explode and search separately as in many case a first name may have two words i.e Jessica Lee

Comment: Based on the example data, if only one part of the data matches both ways, then it sounds as if there is trailing whitespace with the table data? You can check this by running a `LENGTH` check on the data. If there is trailing whitespace, then the `CONCAT` with the space is an extra space (meaning 2 possible spaces, instead of 1) between the first and last name, and is causing the mismatch.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple. This was indeed the answer to my question. Turns out the code above was correct the data just had to trim the data on the way into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar search like this but I didn't use `whereRaw`, instead I did something like this

You can try:

```php
return Patient::where(function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $request->searchTerm . '%')
       ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $request->searchTerm . '%')
       ->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name)'), 'LIKE', '%' . $request->searchTerm . '%');
})->take(50)->get();
```

I know it looks like "well shouldn't it be the same Query with extra step?". Well, it works on my end so try it and let me know :)